# how to take back database in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to take database backup using query so i tried below query

below query run successfully

BACKUP DATABASE interview1 
    TO DISK = 'D:\bp\interview12012.bak';
    GO

but if run below code

```
BACKUP DATABASE interview1 
TO DISK = 'D:\bp\gbp\interview12012.bak';
GO
```

i got error

```
 Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
```

Cannot open backup device 'D:\bp\gbp\interview12012.bak'. Operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

where i made error

Comment: Problem is wrong path check if all directories are existing. If not create them.

Comment: directories is there...

Comment: i cleared the error by creating folder in server system we are using network system....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system cannot find the path specified.change the path and try again.

Comment: i cleared the error by creating folder in server system we are using network system...